# Pattern only domain and category slug via regular expression

Tags: regex

Example URL: https://www.example.com/category_slug/bla-bla-bla 
What I need to get: https://www.example.com/category_slug

I was trying to use masks like this [^/]+(/.+)/ and test it via regextester.com, but still no success as this mask selects the whole url https://www.example.com/category_slug/bla-bla-bla

How could I extract it via regular expression?

Thanks

Comment: The `[^/]+` part will match before the first forward slash in `//`. Try first matching the https like  `^https?://[^/]+/[^/]+` See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/NP6q5q/1)

Comment: Great! Thanks a lot!